# Replacing Python Requests with Pycurl

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pycurl

Iam interested to modify a python module (Discum), replace python requests with pycurl and see if this will brung even a minor improvement in performance. Unfortunately my Pycurl knowledge is limited. Could you please help me replace  the following python requests with the pycurl ones ?

```
self.s = requests.Session()
self.s.headers.update(headers)
```

The theory says that replacing the requests with pycurl ones might improve the speed of the module.

Comment: Preparing HTTP requests is easy.  It is unlikely that your `requests` overhead is more significant than your network latency.  Are you making thousands and thousands of requests?

Comment: first format code and add correct indentations.

Comment: there are pages like https://curlconverter.com/#python to convert from `curl` to `requests` but I never saw page which can convert from `requests` to `curl`.

Comment: Showing many requests in a single post seems to ask you to do your job, it is better to show what is necessary and point out what you have investigated.  Please read [ask]